# Sentry Android: Ignore stacktraces that do not contain my package

Tags: java, android, sentry

I use Sentry in an Android library which is for use by other developers. I get a lot of exceptions from apps using my library but which have nothing to do with the library, and would really like to ignore these. Is there some way to filter exceptions so I only report those that have my library's package somewhere in the stacktrace?

Comment: Could you please add stack trace/ logs to explain/elaborate further your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `ShouldSendEventCallback`:

```
public static void example() {
    SentryClient client = Sentry.getStoredClient();

    client.addShouldSendEventCallback(new ShouldSendEventCallback() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldSend(Event event) {
            // decide whether to send the event

            for (Map.Entry<String, SentryInterface> interfaceEntry : event.getSentryInterfaces().entrySet()) {
                if (interfaceEntry.getValue() instanceof ExceptionInterface) {
                    ExceptionInterface i = (ExceptionInterface) interfaceEntry.getValue();
                    for (SentryException sentryException : i.getExceptions()) {
                        // this example checks the exception class
                        if (sentryException.getExceptionClassName().equals("foo")) {
                            // don't send the event
                            return false;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // send event
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

There is a ticket to make this easier: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-java/issues/575

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with my exact problem, I modified Brett's answer so that it checks the whole stacktrace since the cause of an exception can sometimes be buried in Android.

```
SentryClient client = Sentry.getStoredClient();
client.addShouldSendEventCallback(new ShouldSendEventCallback() {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldSend(Event event) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, SentryInterface> interfaceEntry : event.getSentryInterfaces().entrySet()) {
            if (interfaceEntry.getValue() instanceof ExceptionInterface) {
                ExceptionInterface i = (ExceptionInterface) interfaceEntry.getValue();
                for (SentryException sentryException : i.getExceptions()) {
                    for (SentryStackTraceElement element : sentryException.getStackTraceInterface().getStackTrace()) {
                        if (element.getModule().contains("com.example.library")) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```